# OrmLite Update() vs Save()

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ormlite-servicestack

When using OrmLite to add an entry into the database there seems to be two ways of doing it:

```
dbConn.Insert(customer);
```

and

```
dbConn.Save(customer);
```

When using Insert() the AutoIncrement ID field does not get updated, but when using Save() it does.

If you use:

```
dbConn.LastInsertId();
```

It will return the correct ID if Save() is used but the wrong ID if Insert() is used.

Why do these two methods exist?  Using Insert() will add an entry to the database with the correct ID, it is just not reflected in the POCO model.  It seems strange that there are no exceptions thrown and no indication of a problem, when you can end up using the wrong ID and get hard to track bugs if you are not aware of this.

Comment: already add [AutoIncrement] into your POCO?

Comment: Yes I have [AutoIncrement] attribute on the ID field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's already mentioned in the documentations:

> **Save** and **SaveAll** will Insert if no record with Id exists, otherwise it Updates. Both take multiple items, optimized to perform a single read to check for existing records and are executed within a sinlge transaction.

For **Insert** operation, it's pretty straighforward, there's nothing special in that functions.

So, Use Insert when you know there's **no duplicated key** in your records, otherwise use save method.

If you want to retrieve the LastInsertId, with Insert method, you need to specify the [AutoIncrement] on your POCO.

> UPDATE: When you set your IDbConnectionFactory using **Singelton** With **Lazy< T >** implementation, it seems the LastInsertId will not working. so just use lock or static implementation.

Comment: That is what is strange, LastInsertId returns zero when I use Insert() with the [AutoIncrement] attribute.  I should be using Save() then all the time?  I want the ORM to take care of the ID completely for me.  But what happens if someone else starts to use the code and starts using Insert() and then messes up the wrong records since they are getting the wrong ID back when using Insert()?

Comment: Please share how you use the GetLastInsertId Statement.

Comment: Tried update two ways:
dbConn.Insert(customer, selectIdentity: true);
dbConn.Insert(customer);
then used:
var customerId2 = dbConn.LastInsertId();
I am using V4 of OrmLite so GetLastInsertId does not seem to exist anymore.